# systemd automount ntfs-3g partition gives status=12, can mount maually with the same fstab entry

Tags: systemd, fstab, ntfs-3g

I have a server running with an NTFS harddrive (used as a Samba share), but I can't seem to get it to automount, and I have no idea why. I can mount it manually with 'mount -a'.

my /etc/fstab entry:

```
UUID=615445694442449475    /mnt/shared-git/    ntfs-3g    defaults,users,uid=warepire,gid=users,dmask=0022,fmask=0111     0 0
```

Here's a systemd log from a boot when it failed to automount, the failure is always the same:

```
Jul 28 07:46:37 Nucleus systemd-fstab-generator[121]: Found entry what=/dev/disk/by-uuid/615445694442449475 where=/mnt/shared-git type=ntfs-3g nofail=no noauto=no
Jul 28 07:46:40 Nucleus systemd[1]: mnt-shared\x2dgit.mount: About to execute: /usr/bin/mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/615445694442449475 /mnt/shared-git -t ntfs-3g -o defaults,users,uid=warepire,gid=users,dmask=0022,fmask=0111
Jul 28 07:46:40 Nucleus systemd[1]: mnt-shared\x2dgit.mount: Forked /usr/bin/mount as 184
Jul 28 07:46:40 Nucleus systemd[184]: mnt-shared\x2dgit.mount: Executing: /usr/bin/mount /dev/disk/by-uuid/615445694442449475 /mnt/shared-git -t ntfs-3g -o defaults,users,uid=warepire,gid=users,dmask=0022,fmask=0111
Jul 28 07:46:40 Nucleus systemd[1]: mnt-shared\x2dgit.mount: Changed dead -> mounting
Jul 28 07:46:40 Nucleus systemd[1]: mnt-shared\x2dgit.mount: Child 184 belongs to mnt-shared\x2dgit.mount
Jul 28 07:46:40 Nucleus systemd[1]: mnt-shared\x2dgit.mount: Mount process exited, code=exited status=12
```

According to the ntfs-3g manuals, status 12 means it's not an NTFS partition.

The hard drive was formatted and partitioned from Linux.

Information from fdisk:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 74.5 GiB, 80026361856 bytes, 156301488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x26152614

Device     Boot Start       End   Sectors  Size Id Type
/dev/sda1        2048 156301487 156299440 74.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

systemd --version:

```
systemd 232
+PAM -AUDIT -SELINUX -IMA -APPARMOR +SMACK -SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD +IDN
```

Kernel:

```
Linux Nucleus 4.10.9-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT Sat Apr 8 12:39:59 CEST 2017 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What could be going wrong here?

Comment: I believe that is a known systemd bug, a race condition while mounting, leave the [link](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4812) for you to try the workarouds described there

Comment: Thanks, will give it a try. I added some more information that crossed my mind while reading the github issue.

Comment: @Christopher Díaz Riveros: Gave it a try, nothing changed. It also seems that the problems discussed in the issue are related to EBUSY, and don't happen 100% consistently. I'm still keeping the link as I might encounter it later, after this issue is solved however.